# Access related error using QTP while modifying registry settings

Tags: vbscript, registry, qtp

I have local admin access to my client laptop (which lasts for a session i.e. until you shutdown/restart the system). I can manually change the registry settings however when I use QTP to do the same I get an error as "Invalid root in registry Key". my code is like below:

```
Set objshell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RegLocate ="HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut"
objShell.RegWrite RegLocate, 10000, "REG_SZ"
Set objshell = Nothing
```

what is wrong in this? Do I need to give admin access to myself again via QTP?

if yes, how to do that?

Comment: This looks like a VBScript question not QTP, try doing it in a .vbs file without QTP, if you get the same behaviour you should re-tag the question to **vbs** which will raise the probability of someone answering you.

Comment: Are you sure "REG_SZ" is correct?

Comment: I just ran this code as .vbs instead of running it from QTP. It still didn't change anything in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting the error "Invalid root" because you are not allowed to make this modification.

Try launching UFT (or QTP) with "Run As Administrator", and see if the process works then.